# How to substract values in columns from two different tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am trying to achieve the following.

From the following table of transactions between two users, write a query to return the change in net worth for each user, ordered by decreasing net change.

```
transactions1
+--------+----------+--------+------------------+
| sender | receiver | amount | transaction_date |
+--------+----------+--------+------------------+
|      5 |        2 |     10 | 2-12-20          |
|      1 |        3 |     15 | 2-13-20          |
|      2 |        1 |     20 | 2-13-20          |
|      2 |        3 |     25 | 2-14-20          |
|      3 |        1 |     20 | 2-15-20          |
|      3 |        2 |     15 | 2-15-20          |
|      1 |        4 |      5 | 2-16-20          |
+--------+----------+--------+------------------+
```

From here I have created two views, one with the users that have sent something and the total sent, and another with the users that have received something and the total received. User 5 has not received anything and user 4 has not sent anything so they are not in received/sent views respectively.

```
sent
+--------+------------+
| sender | total_sent |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |         20 |
|      2 |         45 |
|      3 |         35 |
|      5 |         10 |
+--------+------------+

received
+----------+----------------+
| receiver | total_received |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 |             40 |
|        2 |             25 |
|        3 |             40 |
|        4 |              5 |
+----------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to add both users so we have a complete list of users and to substract total_sent from total_received but im not getting a complete list of users. The users that are not in both tables are missing from my result and I'm not sure how can i approach this problem differently.

```
SELECT coalesce(sender,receiver) AS 'user', 
coalesce(total_received,0) - coalesce(total_sent,0) AS 'net_change'
FROM sent s
JOIN received r
ON s.sender = r.receiver
ORDER BY 2 DESC;


RESULT:
+------+------------+
| user | net_change |
+------+------------+
|    1 |         20 |
|    3 |          5 |
|    2 |        -20 |
+------+------------+
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a join, you may perform a union on both sent and received aggregates first and a group by on the resulting union to get the results. The key here is that total_sent is summed as a negative value.

**Option 1: Creating a union on sent and received before determining `net_change`**

```
SELECT
    `user`,
    SUM(`change`) as net_change
FROM (
    SELECT sender as `user`, total_sent*-1 as `change` FROM sent UNION ALL
    SELECT receiver as `user`, total_received as `change` FROM received
) t
GROUP BY 
    `user`
ORDER BY 
    SUM(`change`) DESC;
```

| user | net_change |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | -10 |
| 2 | -20 |

---

**Option 2: Determining `net_change` from the initial table**

```
SELECT
    `user`,
    SUM(`change`) as net_change
FROM (
    SELECT sender as `user`, amount*-1 as `change` FROM transactions1 UNION ALL
    SELECT receiver as `user`, amount as `change` FROM transactions1
) t
GROUP BY 
    `user`
ORDER BY 
    SUM(`change`) DESC;
```

| user | net_change |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | -10 |
| 2 | -20 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8TpA8AT2mRLFio4rVXyqLy/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @ggordon, it worked great. I just have one question, what does the '**t**' mean after the closing parentheses of the **FROM** block? looking to understand MySQL a little bit better as this is my first week with it.

Comment: `t` is being used here as an alias for the subquery (query within the preceding brackets). `t` could be replaced with something alias eg `my_sub`. Subqueries require an alias